# Folder Renaming After Tar Extraction

Tags: bash, shell, tar

I have a tarball, myarchive.tar.gz. When I uncompress it using "tar -zxvf myarchive.tar.gz", it creates a folder myarchive-x980-2303-ssioo. What's the easiest way to automatically rename the extracted folder to ensure it matches the name of the archive? I've checked tar's manpage, but it doesn't seem to have an option for this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Manually create folder, and strip components from tarball:

```
archive=my.tar.gz
mkdir ${archive%.tar*} 
tar --extract --file=${archive} --strip-components=1 --directory=${archive%.tar*}
```

Answer (score 1):

mkdir pretty_name && tar xf ugly_name.tar -C pretty_name --strip-components 1

from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring